# What's a non-toxic flavorless water-soluable chemical I could use for freezing point depression when making ice cream?

Tags: solubility, food-chemistry, taste

I'd like to make a savory version of ice cream. So I can't use sugar or any artificial sweeteners for the freezing point depression needed to control ice crystal sizes. What can I use?

Comment: What gives you the idea that freezing point depression is responsible for (I assume small?) crystallite size?

Comment: I've heard that at various parts of the internet. It doesn't really make sense to me but I'm not knowledgeable enough regarding making ice cream to dispute it.

Comment: http://icecreamscience.com/sugar-in-ice-cream   http://icecreamscience.com/fiber-in-ice-cream/#211_effect_of_increased_viscosity_on_ice_crystal_size   https://foodcrumbles.com/secret-of-ice-cream-freezing-point-depression/   These gave me the idea of that. Maybe I need to look into the fiber one more...